# Returning conditional promise of promises

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, promise

I have the requirement to loop through `diff12` or `diff21`.
In each iteration I am getting a promise returned.

I want to resolve those promises all together only after all iterations happened.

I do not know whether only `diff12` or only `diff21` or both are being looped.

How can I make sure to resolve only those promises that are existent?

Here's how I got so far:

```
var diffPromises: Array<any> = [];

diff12.forEach(currstudent => {
    diffPromises.push(db.collection('users').doc(currstudent).set({
        progress: {
            special: 'special1'
        }
    }, {merge: true}))
})

diff21.forEach(currstudent => { 
    diffPromises.push(db.collection('users').doc(currstudent).set({
        progress: {
            special: 'special2'
                }
            }, {merge: true}))
        })
}

return Promise.all(diffPromises)
```

Comment: Only the promises in the `diffPromises` array will be waited for.   If they're not there, they don't matter.

Comment: I guessed so while editing.
Initially I had two arrays for each loop, which gave me the problem to have two arrays in `Promise.all()`.
I then realized that there is no need for two arrays.
Thanks.